# Why is MeteorJS so popular for making dApps?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, meteor, react, frontend

I am learning more about creating a front end that communicates with solidity contracts. At first, I was pointed in the direction of using ReactJS, but now I see many people talking about using MeteorJS to do this. My question is:

What are some things about MeteorJS that makes it a good framework solution for dApp development?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is so much competition in the JavaScript framework space and they are basically all good if you have good command of it ...

I think  MeteorJS is popular in this space not because it is better than React but because one important member of the Ethereum Foundation **Fabian Vogelsteller** (main contributor of the JavaScript library Web3) wrote several [books about MeteorJS](https://www.amazon.com/Books-Fabian-Vogelsteller/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3AFabian%20Vogelsteller) and was one of the first developing dApp.

Back to September 2015, he said:

> Why Meteor?
>
> Meteor is one of the most complete JavaScript platforms for single
> page applications out there. It comes with all the tools you need for
> development (Dev-Server tool, build tool, live reload, CSS injection,
> pre-compiling, templating engine, client side database, etc), a lot of
> packages (+ every other JS library) and a development team, which
> constantly improves the core freatures.
>
> Additionally the reactive programming model Meteor templates and
> minimongo (Its in-memory DB) use are a real helper to build fast and
> clean consistent interfaces.
>
> Here at ethereum use Meteor for our Ðapps (and most of our websites
> too) and and i've build already a list of Meteor Ðapp packages that
> make building a Ðapp more fun.
>
> [Link](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3462/meteor-for-dapp-development)

But nowadays, you can find very good tutorial and resources to develop dApp in React, Angular or Vue.

In my opinion, the most important point is to have a good understanding of the Ethereum mechanism and the JS library Web3.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor React together is great, checkout "Pup" by The Meteor Chef.... its amazing. They have a full invoicing app template here: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/building-an-invoicing-app

Answer (score 0):

- Meteor is for people who suck at javascript. (okay jokes aside, i'll continue seriously)
- Meteor is a fullstack framework, your smart contract is the back end. You're wasting half of the framework.
- Meteor is good for webapplications because of miniMongo
- Minimongo doesn't do anything for you when using dApps.
- You will be loading in a ****ton of resources you will not use

So why use meteor? Well if you don't know any better ...

I use truffle+vue-CLI , such magic.